# Designing db for multiple forms of a single type

Tags: sql-server, database

What is the best approach to design DB tables for an type which has multiple forms.
For example Animal which can be any animal with its specific properties.

a table for animal with common columns and individual tables for the each type. But how to maintain the foreign key references in the main animal table? We can not keep one key for each type has if the types grow the references will also grow. And for one row  only one type exists and all other keys in the animal table will be null.

Is there any best way to design the tables other than this way?
For example consider the below tables
Furniture table:

```
Id    FurnituretypeId NoofLegs ChairId    TableId
-------------------------------------------------
int   int             int       int        int
```

Chair Table:

```
Id    Name        CansSwing   CanDetachable          
-------------------------------------------------
int   Varchar(25) boolean      boolean
```

Cot Table:

```
Id    Name        CotType      Storage   StorageType
-------------------------------------------------
int   Varchar(35) Varchar(25)  boolean   Varchar(25)
```

Considering the above example if i have to insert the a chair then TableId in Furniture table will be null. If there are multiple types of furniture then i have to add those type ids as foreign keys in Furniture table but at a time only one type i can add.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: You'll want to expand on this some more as well; give specific details on what you want to store, don't just give us the idea of along the lines of "store details about animals". Show us examples of where data differs, for example, and why you feel it should be in a different table.

Comment: Take a look at [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @larnu updated the question with an example.

Comment: Thanks, you haven't updated those tags yet though. :)

Comment: Your question is a well-known topic called SuperTypes and SubTypes (even table inheritance) in relational databases, try googling a little and you will find tons of content.

Comment: Thanks EzLo it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, in case of having multiple properties, would be to create an animal table with all the common stuff, and an animal property table with columns animal(FK),property,value. This, of course, is an un-pivoted solution, which might or might not suit you.